# R: postForm from RCurl headers issue

Tags: r, http, curl, rcurl

I'm trying to make an http post and also retrieve header information using RCurl and I'm seeing some weird behaviour.

Session info:

```
> curlVersion()$version
[1] "7.24.0"
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] en_CA.UTF-8/en_CA.UTF-8/en_CA.UTF-8/C/en_CA.UTF-8/en_CA.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] RCurl_1.95-4.1 bitops_1.0-6
```

I was first seeing weird behaviour making a post to my work's api, but to be sure I tried another website and it is giving me the same behaviour. This works fine:

```
> response <- postForm("http://posttestserver.com/post.php", stuff="Other stuff")
> response
[1] "Successfully dumped 1 post variables.\nView it at http://www.posttestserver.com/data/2013/10/04/{REDACTED}\nPost body was 0 chars long."
attr(,"Content-Type")

"text/html"
```

But I would like to grab header information as well, here's where the fun starts.

```
> h <- basicHeaderGatherer()
> response <- postForm("http://posttestserver.com/post.php", stuff="Other stuff", .opts=curlOptions(headerfunction=h$update))
Successfully dumped 1 post variables.
View it at http://www.posttestserver.com/data/2013/10/04/{REDACTED}
Post body was 0 chars long.> 
> response
NULL
> h$value()
                           Date                          Server     Access-Control-Allow-Origin                            Vary                  Content-Length                    Content-Type                          status 
"Fri, 04 Oct 2013 18:50:14 GMT"                        "Apache"                             "*"               "Accept-Encoding"                           "140"                     "text/html"                           "200" 
              statusMessage 
                       "OK"
```

The colour of the response ("Sucessfully dumped 1...etc") is now gray and outputted when I didn't ask for it, along with it indenting the input chevron. The response variable is NULL, but the headers look fine. And then there is this line (adding verbose=TRUE):

```
response <- postForm("http://posttestserver.com/post.php", stuff="Other stuff", .opts=curlOptions(headerfunction=h$update, verbose=TRUE))
```

Just makes R hang.

I haven't the slightest clue what's going on, any help or a direction to look in would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You forgot closing parentheses on your `postForm` commands. Otherwise, I'm not able to reproduce anything you're showing here.